# AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.NullPointerException when connecting to another class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, paint

Basically I've got the error:

```
run:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PaintV2.UIPanel$1.actionPerformed(PaintGUI.java:line marked)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)'
```

I am trying to link my GUI to a colour class as i am making a paint application. My Questions are: What has gone wrong with my code? and if anyone knows how to fix it,  can you explain how you fixed it please

**My main method:**

```
package PaintV2;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class PaintGUI{

    public static void main(String[] args ){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test panel 2");

        MainPanel panel = new MainPanel();

        UIPanel uip = new UIPanel(panel);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(uip, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(900, 900);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**My MainPanel class:**

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel {   
    int px, py; // radius
    public Color colvals;
    public Colour col;

    public MainPanel(){        
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            // store drag coordinates and repaint
                public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent event )
                {
                        px = event.getX();
                        py = event.getY();
                        repaint();
                }
                }); // end call to addMouseMotionListener
    }

    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {       
        g.setColor(Color.RED); 
        g.fillOval( px, py, 15, 15 );
    }
}
```

**My UIPanel class:**

```
class UIPanel extends JPanel {
    public MainPanel gpanel;
    public Integer data;
    public Color colval;
    public Colour col;

    public UIPanel(MainPanel panel) {
        gpanel = panel;

        Box btnBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        btnBox.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        JButton setBtn = new JButton("Set");

        //code for the colour chooser
        //decided to use a dropdow list with hashmap
        final DefaultComboBoxModel colour = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        colour.addElement("Red");
        colour.addElement("Blue");
        colour.addElement("Yellow");
        colour.addElement("Green");
        final JComboBox colours = new JComboBox(colour);
        JScrollPane colourScroll = new JScrollPane(colours);


        JButton freeBtn = new JButton("FreeHand");
        JButton rectBtn = new JButton("Rectangle");
        JButton circBtn = new JButton("Circle");
        JButton lineBtn = new JButton("line");

        btnBox.add(setBtn);
        btnBox.add(colourScroll);
        btnBox.add(freeBtn);
        btnBox.add(rectBtn);
        btnBox.add(circBtn);
        btnBox.add(lineBtn);
        btnBox.setSize(300, 100);
        btnBox.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        add(btnBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                data= colours.getSelectedIndex();

                col.setCol(data);//This is where the error is being flagged up              
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the Colour Class

```
package PaintV2;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Colour{

    public Color colVal;

     HashMap<Integer, Color> map = new HashMap<Integer, Color>();

    public Colour() {

        map.put(0, Color.RED);
        map.put(1, Color.BLUE);
        map.put(2, Color.YELLOW);
        map.put(3, Color.GREEN);

    }

    public Color setCol(Integer data) {
        return map.get(data);
    }
}
```

Sorry in advance for the massive chunks of code and the code being messy. Also if you need me to edit any bits out to make it more understandable, post or something and I will edit it when i am able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems your just declared `col` and not initialized. try like this..

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    data= colours.getSelectedIndex();
    if(col == null)
        col = new Colour();
    col.setCol(data);//This is where the error is being flagged up              

}
```